# Although I choose to auto-connect, Android Smartphone keeps refusing DSLR's wifi, as no internet found

Tags: smartphone, file-transfer, wifi

The first time connecting my smartphone to DSLR's wifi, I get a message box stating that no internet access could be reached, and asking if I want to keep connection though. So, I just tap "yes, don't ask me again", and everything seems to go well. I use the dedicated Canon/Nikon app, download photos, and disconnect. When I want to connect again, I find that my smartphone doesn't connect automatically to DSLR's wifi. So I open the wifi menu on my smartphone, see my DSLR's network, and tap on it, but I get the weird message "this network is not internet connected, so it wont be used".

I'm not able to get my connection working again until I turn wifi off and on again in both DSLR and Smartphone. Then, it goes as if I was connecting it for the first time. As I work on real-time journalism, this little issue gives me some headaches (specially when my boss wants the photo "right now") either using Canon Camera Connect for EOS 80D and EOS Rebel T6s/760D, or Nikon WMU for D750. I got the same behaviour on Moto G3 when I had one. Might it be a Motorola issue?

Comment: Possibly better answers on the [Android SE site](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Android assumes that the user connects to a WiFi network with the purpose of connecting to the internet. Newer versions of Android (specifically 11 and later) have become more intelligent - when an app initiates the connection to a hotspot, the OS is aware that the purpose to communicate with a specific device rather than the internet and will avoid disconnecting from it automatically.

There's two key parts to this mechanism working:

1. Android is new enough (11+)
2. The connection to the hotspot is initiated by the app, rather than by the user selecting it in WiFi settings. You will see a dialogue similar to this when the app is initiating the connection:

[image: Connect to device dialogue]

Android - as well as the other OSes that implement this functionality, such as Windows - should really have a manual setting for overriding this functionality, but this is not currently available.

Answer (score 0):

Android and also IOS have a check inside the operating system which checks if the wifi has a connection to the internet and only if this check returns true the automatic reconnect is happening. This is done to prevent that the phone is not connected to the internet without the user noticing.

It should not be a problem that you cannot reconnect with the camera if you click on the network in the wifi settings, at least as far as i know and as far as the connection to the camera is a pure wifi connection, not like on for example the nikon d7500, where it is a combination of bluetooth and wifi.

We all know that the vendors apps for the dslrs are not very good and most people use third party apps to get more usability from the wifi connection like for exaple with qdslr dashboard. Honestly I never got enough usability from the connection to the phone out of my camera to use it too much because the transfer to the phone is too slow compared to a direct copy from the card to the computer and also it is easier to work with the raws on the computer.

Comment: Well, the silly thing about this Is that i'm first asked if I want Android to keep on connecting automatically to that non internet network, I choose "yes", but then my answer seems not to have been reminded, it will keep refusing to connect even as I insist selecting DSLR's network.

Comment: if it has a password on it it should be saved and you should connect by just clicking on it. at least thats the case with my d7200 and my sony xperia xa2. but i am a nikon user and don't know how the connection to the canon cameras is etablished. because on a intermediate generation of nikon cameras it was a horror

Comment: @Lisan if you say "yes", that only means that it'll try to connect and probe for an internet connection again next time. but if it doesn't find one, it'll still refuse to connect. usually users want to stay online.

Comment: After some trials, I realized that the only way to prevent this happening is by turning both Smartphone's and DSLR's wifi off every Time I use the app. I mean, I take photos, then turn on wifi, transfer what i need, send it, turn off wifi, and turn it on again if I need some other photo that wasn't downloaded yet. Though, there's some exceptions. A couple of times, I've been able to download, keep wifi on and even take some more photos which could be downloaded on same session

Comment: Last comment was referred to trials I made as I worked was urged to send photos, and kept camera under heavy work. I've just made some new trials with both Nikon d750 and Canon 80d and everything went just ok. I could even take new photos while right at the time when other photos were being downloaded. So I guess the problem has to do with heavy use of DSLRs and smartphone

Comment: When playing with phone to Nikon 7200 WiFi connection, this is what I found: The Nikon App is generally terrible **However**  it does allow you to set the camera to secure WPA with a password. Without that, the camera is a wide open access point for anyone. After setting it to WPA secure, I switched to "*Camera Pro Control*". It's not a free App but it's inexpensive and works well, giving near complete remote control of the camera. Unfortunately, I discovered that the Nikon 7200 will **eat batteries with WiFi enabled**.